# Why won't my SWF embed?

Tags: php, flash, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to embed a SWF on one of my views. Here is the embed code:

```
echo    '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
        codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" 
        width="550" height="400" id="MyProject" align="middle">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="movie" value="'. $this->Html->webroot('/files/'.$project['Project']['id'].'/index.swf') .'" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
        <embed src="'. $this->Html->webroot('/files/'.$project['Project']['id'].'/index.swf') .'" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="550" height="400" 
        name="1" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /></object>';
```

It is supposed to grab the file from `app/webroot/files/1/index.swf` or `app/webroot/files/2/index.swf`, depending on the ID of the project. I've already tried just substituting a 1 or 2 in place of `'.$project['Project']['id'].'`, but it still cannot find the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: highly specific question, check your variable contents, whats the output?

Comment: It is outputting the src as `/cake/files/1/index.swf`. I have the site under `localhost/cake`, so I do not see what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your codes to full url, i.e, output should be in the format of
http://yourdomain.com/files/project_001/index.swf

Make it in such a way that resultant code looks like

```
echo    '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" 
    width="550" height="400" id="MyProject" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://yourdomain.com/'. $this->Html->webroot('/files/'.$project['Project']['id'].'/index.swf') .'" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <embed src="http://yourdomain.com/'. $this->Html->webroot('/files/'.$project['Project']['id'].'/index.swf') .'" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="550" height="400" 
    name="1" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /></object>';
```

You must change all references of this example "http://yourdomain.com/" and add yours.

I hope this helps you,

Good Luck!